# Problem Opening a PDF File with Adobe Reader That Is Downloaded from MySQL database via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, download

I have written some PHP code that downloads a PDF file from a MySQL database on a server.  The code works great and I can view/download/open the PDF file from various browsers.  However, when I download the file and try to open up via Adobe Reader I get a message that says the file could not be opened because "because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)"

I am sure it is something dumb that I am forgetting to do in my code.  Below is the PHP code that I am using:

```
// Downloads files
if (isset($_GET['scenario_id'])) {
    $scenario_id = $_GET['scenario_id'];

    // fetch file to download from database
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM  market_plans_pdfs WHERE scenario_id=$scenario_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    $file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $pdf_file=$file['pdf_file'];


    $filename=$file['scenario_name'];


    if (isset($filename)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');//set content-disposition as "inline" as opposed to "attachment" so that it opens first in the browser
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        @readfile("data:application/pdf;base64,$pdf_file");
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have tried various solutions online with no success.

Comment: `@readfile("data:application/pdf;base64,$pdf_file");` it is not a file so `readfile` is wrong, instead just echo data like: `echo $pdf_file;`, if they are base64 encoded, decode them before

Comment: @Kazz.  Thanks for the quick response.  I have removed the @readfile line with    `echo $pdf_file` and added   `$pdf_file=base64_decode($pdf_file)` prior to the echo.  This also works as before.  I can download/view file but when I try to open via Adobe Reader I get the same message about being unable to open file.

Comment: can you upload your file which cannot be read in adobe reader ?

Comment: @Kazz..  Here is a link to the file in a dropbox folder (https://www.dropbox.com/s/utejtwcydvlieg7/test_upload.pdf?dl=0).  Also, when I uploaded the pdf file, I used `$pdf = base64_encode(file_get_contents(addslashes($pdf)));`

Comment: oh i see it now, you do not separate other output from file itself, make sure there is no output before and after, there is whole website included in that file

Comment: @Kazz.  Sorry for being slow.  Are you saying that I have uploaded more than just the file (captured in the base64 data) or that I have not isolated the file itself on the download?  In either case, can you provide a little more guidance what to change.

Answer (score 1):

When you are changing some headers you have to do it before any output, because header must be sent at the beginning, for example:

This is invalid:

```
echo 'Test';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
```

Thats not your case, but you do similar mistake, on the other end.

When you are printing a file data, for example, as you do in your question, there is no function to tell that "your data ends here", just whole output is taken as file.

If you can't separate your file transfer from other output there is simple solution, try it out:

```
if (isset($filename)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');//set content-disposition as "inline" as opposed to "attachment" so that it opens first in the browser
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    echo base64_decode($pdf_file);
    exit(); // nothing else will happen, no website which is shown otherwise
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt response.  I have tried your code above and still have the same issue.  I can open/view the pdf from the built-in PDF viewer (in browser or Mac) but not when I try to open it up using Adobe Reader.

Comment: Are you sure that you are uploading uncorrupted pdf ? One more thing function `addslashes` in your comment concern me

Comment: Just confirmed that I uploaded an uncorrupted pdf as I can open in Reader.  I also tried to re-upload without `addslashes` and still no luck

Comment: Ok, then idk what exactly it is, examine your pdfs at the hex level, there also wierd text before pdf file, take a look: https://ibb.co/bHdz3rm

Comment: Ok....thanks for your help.  I suspect it has to do with how I capture the data upon upload.  I will look into further.  Again, thanks for you help.